# How to transfer an ERC20 token to a smart contract w/o directly calling token.transfer?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I've an ERC20 token:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _initialSupply)
        ERC20(_name, _symbol)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, _initialSupply);
    }
}
```

I simply want to transfer this token to another Smart Contract- `ContractA` & update its variable using the `addToContract()` function:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract ContractA {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    IERC20 immutable private _token;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balance;

    constructor(address token) {
        require(token != address(0x0));
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }

    function addToContract(uint256 amount) public {
        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        _balance[msg.sender].add(amount);
    }

    function withdrawFromContract(uint256 amount) public {
        require(_balance[msg.sender] >= amount, "Insufficient Stake");
        _token.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        _balance[msg.sender].sub(amount);
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear what I want to achieve. To simply transfer the tokens the user can call `token.transfer()`, but I also want to update a variable `_balances` after that, hence using the function `addToContract()`.

My question is, is the addToContract() function that I've written even possible?

I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible. Your logic is correct :)